# Adding a column in South gives error

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I added a couple of columns and fields to my Django model and was able to run South commands such as:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration [model_name] --auto
$ python manage.py migrate
```

fine on **local machine** without any error. However, when I switch to the server, pulled all new migration+code files and stuff there and did this:

$ python manage.py migrate

It gives me the following error pasted below. I use version MySQL 5.6 (with InnoDB), if that is going to be a useful info. I've tried looking around online and Stackoverflow to find out how to solve this (e.g., [this post](http://agiliq.com/blog/2012/01/south/) comes pretty close to helping me understand the issue, but is not exactly what I'm facing...), but I cannot seem to find the solution to this.

What should I try now to successfully proceed the migration?

```
[root@server: t4s (develop)]$ python manage.py migrate
Running migrations for accounts:
 - Migrating forwards to 0012_auto__add_timelimit.
 > accounts:0005_auto__add_twilioaccount
 > accounts:0006_auto__add_field_twilioaccount_created_at__add_field_twilioaccount_crea
 > accounts:0007_auto__del_twilioaccount
 > accounts:0008_auto__add_twilioaccount
 > accounts:0009_auto__chg_field_twilioaccount_created_by__add_unique_twilioaccount_cre
 > accounts:0010_auto__del_twilioaccount
 > accounts:0011_auto__add_twilioaccount
 > accounts:0012_auto__add_timelimit
 - Loading initial data for accounts.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for smsmessages:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for smsmessages.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for organizations:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for organizations.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for campaigns:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_auto__add_field_taskqueue_twilio.
 > campaigns:0003_auto__add_field_taskqueue_twilio
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   - no dry run output for delete_foreign_key() due to dynamic DDL, sorry
   = ALTER TABLE `campaigns_taskqueue` DROP COLUMN `twilio_id` CASCADE; []

 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS (one that supports DDL transactions)
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Error in migration: campaigns:0003_auto__add_field_taskqueue_twilio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 220, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 254, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 329, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 133, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration, database)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 114, in run
    return self.run_migration(migration, database)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 8
    migration_function()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 6
    return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/opt/dev/t4sfeature/t4sdev/t4s/campaigns/migrations/0003_auto__add_field
    keep_default=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 47, in _ca
    return func(self, table, *args, **opts)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 418, in ad
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 282, in ex
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, i
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, i
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 175, in exe
    if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 89, in _war
    warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: TIME/TIMESTAMP/DATETIME columns of old format have been upgraded
```

When I tried running `python manage.py migrate` again, I got a slightly different error as follows.

```
[root@server: t4s (develop)]$ python manage.py migrate
Running migrations for accounts:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for accounts.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for smsmessages:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for smsmessages.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for organizations:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for organizations.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
Running migrations for campaigns:
 - Migrating forwards to 0003_auto__add_field_taskqueue_twilio.
 > campaigns:0003_auto__add_field_taskqueue_twilio
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE `campaigns_taskqueue` ADD COLUMN `twilio_id` integer NULL;
The error was: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'twilio_id'")
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   - no dry run output for delete_foreign_key() due to dynamic DDL, sorry
   = ALTER TABLE `campaigns_taskqueue` DROP COLUMN `twilio_id` CASCADE; []

 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS (one that supports DDL transactions)
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Error in migration: campaigns:0003_auto__add_field_taskqueue_twilio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/management/commands/migrate.py", line 111, in handle
    ignore_ghosts = ignore_ghosts,
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/__init__.py", line 220, in migrate_app
    success = migrator.migrate_many(target, workplan, database)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 254, in migrate_many
    result = migrator.__class__.migrate_many(migrator, target, migrations, database)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 329, in migrate_many
    result = self.migrate(migration, database)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 133, in migrate
    result = self.run(migration, database)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 114, in run
    return self.run_migration(migration, database)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 84, in run_migration
    migration_function()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 60, in <lambda>
    return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/opt/dev/t4sfeature/t4sdev/t4s/campaigns/migrations/0003_auto__add_field
    keep_default=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 47, in _ca
    return func(self, table, *args, **opts)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 418, in ad
    self.execute(sql)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/south/db/generic.py", line 282, in ex
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, i
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, i
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, i
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 173, in exe
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'twilio_id'")
```

The lastest south migration file (named `0003_auto__add_field_taskqueue_twilio.py`) regarding `campaigns` models has this:

```
u'campaigns.taskqueue': {
    'Meta': {'object_name': 'TaskQueue'},
    'campaign': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'to': u"orm['campaigns.Campaign']"}),
    'created_at': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {'auto_now_add': 'True', 'blank': 'True'}),
    'created_by': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'to': u"orm['auth.User']"}),
    'groups': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField', [], {'to': u"orm['organizations.Group']", 'symmetrical': 'False'}),
    u'id': ('django.db.models.fields.AutoField', [], {'primary_key': 'True'}),
    'launch_time': ('django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField', [], {}),
    'status': ('django.db.models.fields.CharField', [], {'default': "'pending'", 'max_length': '30'}),
    'twilio': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'to': u"orm['accounts.TwilioAccount']", 'null': 'True'})
},
```

As far as I remember, I just added this line to the `campaigns/models.py` file:

```
class TaskQueue(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign)
    launch_time = models.DateTimeField()
    twilio = models.ForeignKey(TwilioAccount, null=True) # new line recently added

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and `TwilioAccount` model is like this:

```
class TwilioAccount(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)
    sid = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. I read through South's migration file and git commit logs as well as checked my DB tables and realized there's a column named `twilio` already created (not sure when and how). After ensuring everything looks good, I used the recommendation of this [very useful post](http://agiliq.com/blog/2012/01/south/) (provided in the question above) by doing:

```
$ python manage.py migrate 0003 --fake
```

That allowed me to skip the migration #3 (I don't need it because I already have `twilio` column created in my DB) and proceed to next steps in coding. I hope someone who face the same error will find this useful.